# `acronym` package: link uses of acronyms to the list of acronyms without linking list entries to first uses of acronyms

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, hyperlink

### The Problem

I'm creating a document using the [`acronym` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym). I want to have my uses of `\ac`, `\Ac`, `\iac`, etc. link to the corresponding entry in my list of acronyms (created using the `acronym` environment), but I do *not* want the acronyms in the list to be hyperlinks to their first uses. How do I do this?

### MWE

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

The \ac{QBF} jumps over \iac{LD}. The \ac{LD} jumps over \iac{QBF}.

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{QBF}{quick brown fox}
    \acro{LD}{lazy dog} \acrodefindefinite{LD}{an}{a}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

#### Desired Output

> Note that the hyperlinks in the "Desired Output" section *do not actually go anywhere*. They are intended to demonstrate where hyperlinks appear in the outputted document.
>
> **Description:** In the text of the document, all uses of the acronym link to the corresponding entry in the list of acronyms. In the list of acronyms (within the `acronym` environment), the entries are not hyperlinks.

The quick brown fox ([QBF](https://null.invalid)) jumps over a lazy dog ([LD](https://null.invalid)). The [LD](https://null.invalid) jumps over a [QBF](https://null.invalid).

**QBF** quick brown fox
**LD** lazy dog

#### Actual Output

> Note that the hyperlinks in the "Actual Output" section *do not actually go anywhere*. They are intended to demonstrate where hyperlinks appear in the outputted document.
>
> **Description:** In the text of the document, all uses of the acronym link to the corresponding entry in the list of acronyms. In the list of acronyms (within the `acronym` environment), each entry links back to the first use of its respective acronym in the document.

The quick brown fox ([QBF](https://null.invalid)) jumps over a lazy dog ([LD](https://null.invalid)). The [LD](https://null.invalid) jumps over a [QBF](https://null.invalid).

[**QBF** quick brown fox](https://null.invalid)
[**LD** lazy dog](https://null.invalid)

### What I tried

Based on section 4.2 of [the `acronym` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf), which discusses the implementation of the package, I was hopeful that this would solve the problem, but it didn't work.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

The \ac{QBF} jumps over \iac{LD}. The \ac{LD} jumps over \iac{QBF}.

{\makeatletter\AC@nohyperlinkstrue\makeatother
    \begin{acronym}
        \acro{QBF}{quick brown fox}
        \acro{LD}{lazy dog} \acrodefindefinite{LD}{an}{a}
    \end{acronym}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `\acrodefindefinite` has *three mandatory arguments*, e.g., `\acrodefindefinite{LD}{an}{a}`. Because you are using only two argument, your examples result in errors. Please, see the manual for more information how to use it.

To not have links from the list of acronyms to the usage of the acronyms, you can locally redefine `\AC@hyperref` *inside* the environment. To do so, either add

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\AC@hyperref[#1]#2{#2}
\makeatother
```

immediately after `\begin{acronym}` or use the generic LaTeX hook mechanism (see `lthooks-doc.pdf` for more information):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/acronym/begin}{\def\AC@hyperref[#1]#2{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The \ac{QBF} jumps over \iac{LD}. The \ac{LD} jumps over \iac{QBF}.

\section*{List of acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{QBF}{quick brown fox}
  \acro{LD}{lazy dog}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image: links to the list of acronyms but not the usage of the acronyms]